# How to fix my LEDS not responding to the limit switch and stop it from cycling through the if else statement?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I am making a script for an arduino board that will use a stepper motor to hit a limit switch which will then light up some LEDS (right now in only have 1 LED set), the code seems sound to me, it should be lighting up when the limit switch is pressed and then turn off when it is released but it is not doing this at all? Also, its reading my if else statements like normal lines of code and goes through all without looking at the conditions. Could someone read over my code and spot what I've done wrong?

Here is the code:

```
void updateLEDS() {
limitSwitchPin.loop();
if(limitSwitchPin.getState() == HIGH) {
 if(limitSwitchPin.isPressed()); 
  digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
  Serial.println("LED 1");
  delay(500);
 }
else(limitSwitchPin.getState() == LOW); {
  if(limitSwitchPin.isReleased())
   digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);
   Serial.println("led low 2");
  delay(500);
```

Entire Code:

```
//Libaries
#include <ezButton.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

//Constants
const float STEPS_PER_REV = 32;
const float GEAR_RED = 64;
const float STEPS_PER_OUT_REV = STEPS_PER_REV * GEAR_RED;

int StepsRequired;

//Stepper Motor Pre-Setup
Stepper steppermotor(STEPS_PER_REV, 8, 10, 9, 11);

//LED PRE-Setup
int LED_2 = 5;

//Switch Pre-Setup
ezButton limitSwitchPin(7);



//Previous Variables 
unsigned long previousLED_2Millis = 0;
unsigned long  currentMillis = 0;

//==========================

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
int currentMillis = millis();
int ledState = digitalRead(LED_2);
pinMode(LED_2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(7, INPUT);
limitSwitchPin.setDebounceTime(100);

Serial.begin(9600);
}
//==========================

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

//clockWise();
updateLEDS();
}

//==========================

void clockWise() {
StepsRequired = - STEPS_PER_OUT_REV / 2;
steppermotor.setSpeed(1000);
steppermotor.step(StepsRequired);
Serial.println("clockWise 4");
};


void updateLEDS() {
limitSwitchPin.loop();
if(limitSwitchPin.getState() == HIGH) {
 if(limitSwitchPin.isPressed()); 
  digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
  Serial.println("LED 1");
  delay(500);
 }
else(limitSwitchPin.getState() == LOW); {
  if(limitSwitchPin.isReleased())
   digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);
   Serial.println("led low 2");
  delay(500);
}
//}
};
```

I have tried everything in my powder as a novice coder, changing the code around seeing if it would work and adding a delay so it could maybe fix the fact that its skipping over the if else conditions, it dint help.

Comment: I'm not sure if Arduino compiler has any warning flags, but at the very least you can run your code through [automatic formatter](http://format.krzaq.cc/) to highlight some issues - you have quite a few extra `;` and (probably) missing `{}` around your `if` and `else`. I don't really know how to use this `limitSwitchPin` (and whether it's expected to check for both `getState() == HIGH` and `isPressed()` at the same time), so I can't write an answer.

Comment: When I was looking around online when first starting this project, someone told me that I had to have both. First it would check if the limitswitch was "HIGH" and then if it was pressed. I've tried removing both the  "getState() == HIGH" and only having "isPressed()" in the code and vice versa and the LED dint even light up at all when I did that so I think I need both for it to function.

Comment: As I said, I don't know whether this is correct or not. But you definitely have extra `;` around, and `else` takes no condition, no idea what you wanted to express there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't have extra ; around the else. I've tried removing all of them, and by the time I fixed all of the error messages, I had the same amount of ";" as before I deleted them all. Okay, that is fine, I don't know either, that's why I'm here ahaha.

Comment: `if(limitSwitchPin.isPressed());` - this `;` doesn't belong here. Basically it's going to make this `if` skipped everytime. `else` is separate issue, `else` is just `else`, there shouldn't be any condition near that. Did you mean `else if` instead?

Comment: Every time you find yourself typing `if(....);` you should realize nothing will happen.  Turn on proper warnings to keep from making this mistake.  `;` is a legal C/C++ expression, but does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your intention is, but the indentation does not appear to match the braces.
In general it is good practice to always use {} and proper indentation for if and else statements, even if it is not necessary.
This is to avoid issues later.

Also: don't use `if (condition) ; {...}`, because the code in braces will always be executed. You must leave out the `;`.

Finally: an `if (input == HIGH)` does not need an `else if (input == LOW)`, just 'else' will do (ignoring the fact that you apparently forgot the second if).

So I guess your code **could** be:

```
void updateLEDS() {
    limitSwitchPin.loop();
    if(limitSwitchPin.getState() == HIGH) {
        if(limitSwitchPin.isPressed()) {
            digitalWrite(LED_2, HIGH);
            Serial.println("LED 1");
            delay(500);
        }
    } else {
        if(limitSwitchPin.isReleased()) {
            digitalWrite(LED_2, LOW);
            Serial.println("led low 2");
            delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, not sure if those are your intentions, but formatting it this way should help you solve your problem.

I am ignoring some other issues, like the `.getState()`, `.isPressed()`, and `isReleased` methods that appear to be duplicated, but the presence of the `delay(500)` suggests that this duplication was intended to debounce the switches before the code got mangled...